# aws application load balancer metrics not showing

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created an aws application load balancer.  I am trying to test something out on it and I have configured the target group and everything.  When I try to hit the load balancer I get a bad gateway error (502), which is expected.  However these metrics are not showing up in the monitoring section of the load balancer.  I submitted around 5 requests.

Furthermore even after registering an ECS service, I still get bad gatewawy.  This is what I see on the load balancer/target groups after registering the service

I have also allowed all traffic inbound and outbound from the two security groups (the security group used by the ECS service and the security group used by the load balancer)

[image]
[image]

However under the registered target when creating the ECS service I specified two availability zones, but it shows only one registered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you waited at least 5 min and also, have you checked the same metrics in cloudwatch?

Comment: yup I have waited for 10 minutes actually, also I cannot navigate to the ECS service after registering it, but I can access it form the public ip of the service.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out and its kind of silly.  My VPN/network was blocking the call going out to the ALB.  I'm not sure why, maybe some sort of network policy.  But the url looks something like this `my-lb-1123366532.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`  I wasted almost a day trying to figure this out.  I'm just putting it out here in case it helps someone.